# How to convert Process to a HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webapi

What I am looking at is a piece of code that is suppose to translate to a given language for a given Html file using process .
Here

- htmlfile - File to translate
- target_language - Language to translate to
- chekoutTime - Time limit for how long function will wait for processing translation on server
- The function will return the input HTML code in the file as a string

What confuses me is the while loop in the middle. I am not sure how to refactor it using HttpClient in one go.
Any suggestion will be helpful
Thank you in advance

```
public static async Task<string> TranslateHTMLFileAsync(FileInfo htmlfile, Language target_language, int checkOutTime = 90)
{       
    if (target_lang == "") 
            throw new Exception("Desired language is not supported.");
    if (!htmlfile.Extension.ToLower().Contains("htm")) 
            throw new Exception("File provided for translation is not in HTML format");
    
    string key = GlobalSetting.Get("APIKeys").StringValue;

    

    string procoutput;
    using (Process proc = new Process())
    {
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "curl";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"https://devapi.com/v2/document -F \"file=@{htmlfile.FullName}\" -F \"auth_key={key}\" -F \"target_lang={target_lang}\"";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        proc.Start();
        procoutput = await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }

    if (!procoutput.Contains("document_id") 
        throw new Exception($"Upload document failed with output: {procoutput}");

    UploadDocumentResponse uploadResponse = Functions.DeserializeJSON<UploadDocumentResponse>(procoutput);
   

    DateTime processingStartedAt = DateTime.Now;
    CheckDocumentResponse checkResponse = null;

    await Task.Delay(5000);

    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        procoutput = string.Empty;
        using (var proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "curl";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"https://devapi.com/v2/document/{uploadResponse.document_id} -d \"auth_key={key}\" -d \"document_key={uploadResponse.document_key}\"";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            proc.Start();
            procoutput = await proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }

        if (!procoutput.Contains("document_id")
            throw new Exception($"Check document request on API failed with output: {procoutput}");
            
        checkResponse = Functions.DeserializeJSON<CheckDocumentResponse>(procoutput);
        if (checkResponse.status == "error") 
            throw new Exception("Document translation on API failed!");
        if (checkResponse.status == "done") break;

        if (DateTime.Now > processingStartedAt.AddSeconds(checkOutTime)) 
            throw new Exception($"Timeout ({checkOutTime} seconds) occured while waiting for document to be translated.");
    }

     // Download and return the translated HTML code.
 // here I have used the HttpClient to read the HTML file that is translated.
 // I need to do that same for the above process part as well. 
    
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "document_key", uploadResponse.document_key },
            { "auth_key", key }
        };

    FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"https://devapi.com/v2/document/{uploadResponse.document_id}/result", content);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        throw new Exception($"API translate request failed on download - {response.StatusCode}");
    string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();       
    return html;
}
```

Class that holds the id and key for the given HTML document.

```
 public class UploadDocumentResponse
        {
            public string document_id { get; set; }
            public string document_key { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the same pattern you see at the end? What code have you written, and what doesn't work when you try that? And what do you mean by "in one go?" (You're not going to be able to consolidate all these requests into a single request, for example.)

Comment: The bit using `HttpClient` does a URL encoded form upload request, which is the same thing the `curl` call in that `while(true)` does. In fact, it does almost the same thing with the only difference being the `result` at the end of the URL. You could (and really _should_) rewrite the whole thing to only use `HttpClient`.

Comment: I just wanted to have one instance of HttpClient when i am inside the while loop. That is the part I am confused about

Comment: Why create a  httpclient instance before loop not work?